# Listview data from multiple db rows

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am currently using a listview populated from a SQLite db.

```
public Set<String> getData() {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    String selectQuery = "select * from " + TABLE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            set.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return set;
}
```

then the list view is populated with

```
private void populateListView() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSetLocks);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    Set<String> set = db.getData();

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list );

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    registerForContextMenu(lv);

}
```

this all works perfectly. Ive decided to change the layout a bit and use a 2 line listview so I need to access the data in different rows of the database.

Whats the best way for me to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I think you're asking perhaps try reading this:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html Lars Vogel does very good tutorials

You'll do better creating a custom adapter by extending the Array or Cursor adapter.

Maybe have a look at:
http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to create a [custom listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) . Custom list view allows you to inflate a custom list item layout with multiple view/textviews.

For database so simply need two queries to fetch different column values in the following way :

```
String selectQueryCombined = "select "+ col1+","+col2+"from " + TABLE;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

//To Retrieve value  :

String val=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Col1));
String val1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Col));
```

Now just set these values in textviews of your custom listview item .

Hope this helps!